Type incompatibility issue when registering @fastify/multipart in a NestJS application with Fastify
I am working on a NestJS application using Fastify and I am having trouble registering the @fastify/multipart plugin. Here is my setup:
import multiPart from '@fastify/multipart';
import { NestFastifyApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';
import { RawServerDefault } from 'fastify';

export const setupPlugins = async (app: NestFastifyApplication<RawServerDefault>) => {
    await app.register(multiPart, {
        limits: {
            fileSize: 1000000,
        }
    });
}

I have tried updating the dependencies to the latest versions:
npm install fastify@latest
npm install @fastify/multipart@latest
npm install @nestjs/platform-fastify@latest

However, I keep getting the following compilation error:
Compilation error in /usr/app/src/app/setup/plugins.ts
error TS2345: Argument of type 'FastifyMultipartPlugin' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FastifyPluginCallback<FastifyMultipartOptions> | FastifyPluginAsync<FastifyMultipartOptions> | Promise<...> | Promise<...>'.
  Type 'FastifyMultipartPlugin' is not assignable to type 'FastifyPluginCallback<FastifyMultipartOptions>'.
    Types of parameters 'instance' and 'instance' are incompatible.
      Type 'FastifyInstance<RawServerDefault, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse<IncomingMessage>, FastifyBaseLogger, FastifyTypeProviderDefault>' is missing the following properties from type 'FastifyInstance<RawServerDefault, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse<IncomingMessage>, FastifyBaseLogger, FastifyTypeProviderDefault>': propfind, proppatch, mkcalendar, mkcol, and 8 more.

I have tried the following solutions without success:

Enabling esModuleInterop and allowSyntheticDefaultImports in tsconfig.json.
Using require instead of import.
Aligning the versions of the dependencies

My current dependency setup is:

fastify@4.28.1
@nestjs/platform-fastify@10.4.8
@fastify/multipart@8.3.0

I would appreciate any help to resolve this type incompatibility issue. Thanks!

I've identified the problem. Using require solves the issue, but you need to consider the synchronization and remove the async/await.
Also, I used @fastify/multipart@8.3.0, and I made sure from the changelog that it is compatible with Fastify 4.x."
